# When trading lava with a armorer, does the bucket remain?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a villager trading hall with an armorer. It trades a lava bucket for an emerald. To make sure I don't waste iron, does the bucket remain in the trade slot when I trade with the villager (the bucket empties)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Villager Trading

When trading with villagers, console has gotten a huge change to trading. You can see these changes at the Official Minecraft Wiki [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading). To answer your question, trading a lava bucket to a villager will also take the bucket. Think of it like this. If you wanted a lava bucket and traded an emerald to a player, you'd want the bucket to hold this lava. They can't put lava in their pants without dying.

Comment: I don't play on console. I play on an iPad MCPE, and please provide an actual explanation, not a "smart" or common-sense one.

Comment: @fasterthanlight BE includes PE, and your actual explanation is that they take the bucket as well, just like any other item. For example, a liberarian can be traded 4 books for an emerald. It takes four books in return for the emerald you earned.